# Meaning of sentence

Tags: meaning

What is meaning of

> I believe the struggle for financial freedom is unfair. I believe the only ones who disagree are millionaires.

?

Comment: Only millionaires disagree with the notion that folks are struggling to achieve financial security.

Comment: It means exactly what it says. There are no metaphors or idioms that need to be explained. What part of it are you finding confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ambiguous.  The first sentence may mean the writer believes that the fact of a struggle existing in the first place is unfair (everyone should either have it already, or no one should struggle for it), or that it is conduced in an unfair manner.